# Why i'm getting Error for deprecated Class in Firestore SDK for PHP?

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

After upgrading to newer version of 'google/cloud-firestore' i'm getting an error.

That's error got:

> Google\Cloud\Firestore\V1beta1\StructuredQuery_CollectionSelector
>   is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. Use
>   Google\Cloud\Firestore\V1beta1\StructuredQuery\CollectionSelector
>   instead at
>   /var/www/procare-vendor/google/cloud/Firestore/src/V1beta1/StructuredQuery_CollectionSelector.php 15

There is my composer.json

```
    {
  "require": {
    "phpoffice/phpexcel" : "1.8.1",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~5.2",
    "katzgrau/klogger": "dev-master",
    "itbz/fpdf": "1.7.3",
    "microsoft/windowsazure" : "*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "google/cloud-firestore": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

PHP version 7.0.31
with gRPC extension installed

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @NicoHaase question is in the title: 'Why i'm getting Error for deprecated Class in Firestore SDK for PHP?'

Comment: Okay. Then it's obvious: a deprecated class is used

Comment: @NicoHaase it's not obvious. As you can see error comes from SDK, i'm not using this class. It's used by sdk: 'vendor/google/cloud/Firestore/src/V1beta1/StructuredQuery_CollectionSelector.ph 15'

Comment: That is only the line throwing that error message. You should search which lines of code use that class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

I have had an custom error handler in my project, which overwrites default php error handling and all configurations for error handling.

That's the code:

```
//Deal with catchable PHP errors
if (AppConfig::resolveEnv() != AppConfig::ENV_LIVE && ! Request::getInstance()->isInConsole) {
    set_error_handler(function ($errno , $errstr, $errfile = null, $errline = null, $errcontext = array() ) {

        $ex = new AppException("{$errstr} at {$errfile} {$errline}");
        Application::getInstance()->renderKernelPanicAlert($ex);
    }, E_ALL);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using `ext-protobuf`? If so, the best solution is to just silence `E_USER_DEPRECATED` messages.

If you're using a custom error handler, you can configure it to skip that error type:

```
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr) {
    // Keep existing error handling
}, E_ALL ^ E_USER_DEPRECATED);
```

If not, just set your `error_reporting` ini option (or `error_reporting()` function value) to `E_ALL^E_USER_DEPRECATED`.

Are you using `google/cloud-firestore` v1.1? If so, and if you are not using the protobuf extension, it may be an issue which should be addressed.

Comment: I'm not using ext-protobuf as php extension. Do you mean that i'm using 'ext-protobuf' as PHP extension? I checked my composer.lock file and found that the 'ext-protobuf' is installed as dependency of few packages.

Comment: In any case, excluding `E_USER_DEPRECATED` from your error handler will fix the problem.